# Como editar uma entidade que possui um outro objeto em jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

Boa tarde galera, sou novo em programação e estou tendo problemas com o meu projeto em jsf. Tenho uma classe cliente que possui um objeto endereço, com relacionamento `@OneToOne` para o endereço. Estou conseguindo consultar o meu endereço dentro do método de edição. O que eu não estou conseguindo fazer é trazer os dados do meu endereço e exibir na página de cadastro do cliente, sendo que os dados do cliente são carregados normalmente, porém ele não traz o endereco.

**ClienteBean:**

```
public String alterar() {
    try {
        this.cliNovo = null;
        this.cliNovo = fach.consultarCliente(this.cliente.getId());

        if(cliNovo.getEndereco().getId() != null) {
            cliNovo.getEndereco().getLogradouro();
            cliNovo.getEndereco().getNumero();
            cliNovo.getEndereco().getEstado();
            cliNovo.getEndereco().getBairro();
            cliNovo.getEndereco().getEstado();
        }
        fach.atualizarCliente(cliNovo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "/cadastrocli.xhtml?faces-redirect-true";
    //"cadastrocli";
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo SOpt! Desculpe, mas da forma que você colocou a pergunta fica difícil entender o que você precisa. Nós não conhecemos o domínio do seu problema! Se você puder especificar melhor qual a sua dúvida, com ênfase no código, poderemos te ajudar mais.

Comment: Então, a ideia é recuperar os dados de um cliente específico e fazer as alterações, o que não estou conseguindo retornar do banco e exibir no meu form são os dados que são referentes ao endereço, sendo o cliente possui uma fk desse endereço em um relacionamento um-pra-um.

Comment: Olá Carlos, o que o Genos quis dizer é que só com o que temos acima não dá para diagnosticar o que está acontecendo. Eu assumo que `fach.consultarCliente` está indo buscar os dados no DB usando JPA correto? Pode ser que seu relacionamento seja *lazy* e não exista uma sessão aberta na *view* para recuperar os dados do endereço. Provavelmente se você chamar `getEndereco()` no lugar correto estes dados serão carregados e propagados para a *view*, dito isso, sem um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) fica difícil te dar uma resposta completa. Você poderia atualizar sua pergunta?

Comment: Poe a implementação das entidades... Junto das anotações do jpa